# Why the android keyboard automatically wrap the bottom button layout in top?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm develop the android app layout, The layout screen bottom having the button and the above layout `Edittext`, the keyboard to the `Edittext` requestfocus that time the bottom button comes up on the screen.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Define this:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden"
```

under your activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: If i'm using this one means, The inside scroll view content is not shown fully.

Comment: You could try `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing|stateHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Manifest activity

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"
```